# compare two columns from two different tables in oracle sql for differences

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi first time posting for SQL,

I need to compare two different columns from two different tables in SQL.

For example there is two tables and each have one column in them and I need to compare them.

Column1 is in table1 and column2 is in table2.

I need to compare column1 and column2 for differences, I have looked online but was unable to find a query that would be able to help.

Essentially I need to find the inconsistencies in the two columns from two different tables.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare for differences"? Are you trying to find values that appear in both? values that appear only in one column? Please go into details.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  "Compare for differences" is quite vague.

Comment: Ok I will. I need to find the differences in data that exist in one but does not exists in the other. Inconsistencies in the data columns.

Comment: select * from table1 A where not exists (select 1 from table2 b where b.column=a.column);

Answer (score 1):

You can do inner join and then find the difference.

```
SELECT
       table1.column1,
       table2.column2, 
      (CASE WHEN (table1.column1 = table2.column2 THEN 'No change' ELSE 'Change DETECTED' END)) AS Difference
FROM
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: The first query shows that the inner join is expecting a: (     And on the second one I get that table2.id is an invalid identifier

Comment: What about the third one?

Comment: I get an ora-01722: invalid number.

Comment: I am comparing multiple rows in each column. I have been trying it for two days and tried the methods above. I need to compare the values in each row and find differences between those two columns. Basically the inconsistencies of data between the two columns.

Comment: I have edited the third query..pls check..

`ora-01722: invalid number` means either one of ur column(col1 OR clo2 OR Both) are not an Integer/Number. Check ur format of respective column

Comment: They are not integers, they are characters. I need to compare the values between the two tables.

Comment: lexographical order comaprison?

Comment: Okay the problem asked to find the inconsistencies between those two tables. One of the tables have the value TZ543 and the other table has the value TZ54,3. That is the problem, the value should be equal on both columns on each table. So I need to find the inconsistent values and filter them out

Comment: so that means you can do inner join.?

Comment: Yes, but I need the values that are inconsistent to be applied in the output

Comment: Same error as before ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: FYI.You cant use if in oracle sql.You can only use it in an anonymous block which is through pl/sql

Comment: Oh.. then you can use `CASE WHEN`, check the edit in query and try.

Answer (score 0):

The following Oracle SQL would be a solution provided you have an `id` that you can join on between the two tables.

```
 select tab1.id,
           case
            when tab1.col1 > tab2.col1 OR tab1.col1 < tab2.col1 then 'Different'
            else 'Equals'
           end
    from tab1, tab2
    where tab1.id = tab2.id;
```

Test data SQL:

```
create table tab1 ( id number, col1 varchar2(20));
create table tab2 ( id number, col1 varchar2(20));
insert into tab1 values (1, 'ABCD');
insert into tab1 values (2, 'EFGH');
insert into tab1 values (3, 'WXYZ');
insert into tab2 values (1, 'ABCD');
insert into tab2 values (2, 'EFG');
insert into tab2 values (3, 'ZYXW');
commit;
```

Results:

```
    ID CASEWHENT
```

---

```
     1 Equals
     2 Different
     3 Different
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    WITH x AS (SELECT 1 AS ID, 'THE QUICK BROWN' AS tab1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 AS ID, 'FOX JUMPS OVER' AS tab1  FROM dual),
         y AS (SELECT 1 AS ID, 'THE QUICK BROWN FOX' AS tab2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 AS ID, 'FOX JUMPS OVER' AS TAB2 FROM DUAL)

SELECT   X.ID,X.tab1,Y.tab2,(CASE WHEN (X.tab1 = tab2) 
                             THEN 'Tab1 is equal  Tab2'
                             ELSE 'Tab1 is not equal to Tab2' END) AS Remarks
FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON X.ID = Y.ID;
```

OUTPUT:

```
    ID       TAB1                 TAB2                     REMARKS   
    1  THE QUICK BROWN      THE QUICK BROWN FOX     Tab1 is not equal to Tab2 
    2  FOX JUMPS OVER       FOX JUMPS OVER          Tab1 is equal  Tab2
```